# Entering Schengen region before 180 days in 90/180 rule

Tags: air-travel, visas, europe, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I have been issued Schengen visa for 1 year. All 90 days exhausted out of 180 days in my last visit to Italy.

Its been only a month I have reached my country India.  May need to travel back again to Europe for work. The visa process was not self initiated , it was by my employer.

Is it possible to re-enter before 180 days through anyway. If so, want to understand the way out / process to re-enter Schengen area before 180 days rule.

Comment: If you spent 3 whole months in Italy, and now need to go back again after a month away, it doesn't sound like you're a casual visitor. My hunch is you'll need to apply for a different kind of visa, more suited to the large amounts of time you're spending there

Answer (score 7):

If you want to stay longer than 90 days within a 180 days period, you need a national long-term (type D) visa. Even if your 90/180-visa (type C?) is still valid, it should at least in theory be possible to "upgrade" it to a type D visa. If you are going to Italy to work, you will also need a work permit. I am note sure if you can apply for that together with the visa, or if there are separate application processes.

A national type D visa gives you the right to a long term stay in the issuing country and in practice the same rights as a type C visa in the other Schengen countries. You are allowed to transit and visit other Schengen countries within the same limits as the citizens of the issuing country. This may be a problem if you need to transit other Schengen countries to get to Italy. Even if you get a new type D visa from Italy, I would assume that your 90 days are considered to be used and that the new visa in this case won't give you the right to enter or transit other Schengen countries.

You should however discuss this with the Italian consulate and be able to get any necessary details on what you are entitled to with a new visa, if they should issue one to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an on line tool that will help you calculate how many days you can stay in Schengen.
You enter the dates of entry and exit for past days, and as "control" date the day of your next visit. You will then be given how many days you can stay.
You can find this tool here:
http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html

Comment: I understand within 180 days i can plan 90 days. All the days i.e 90 days got covered in single visit. I have not stayed more than 30 days in India after i reached from Italy. May need to plan for travel again then what is the way out to enter Italy as still 60 days are left to reenter as per 90/180 rule.

Comment: In this case you can't yet return, as in the last 180 days (as of now) you have already used up your 90 days. If you have stayed a full 90 days in Italy you must now first stay 90 days outside of Schengen.

Comment: Even i apply a new VISA it is not possible?

Comment: @RKT The 90 days rule does not depend on visas but applies to you as a person, you cannot be more than 90 days in a 180-day period in the Schengen area without a type D visa, residence permit or (obviously) being a citizen of an EU or associated country. It doesn't matter if you have one or several visas, when and where you apply, if you have several passports, etc.